# Best way to return multiple ActionResults to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am a newbie in MVC so please bear with me. I need to know a good technique to return multiple ActionResults to the view and display each in its own blank page. I have the following foreach loop returning a result as a FileContentAction. Of course this one returns only one item in list of the loop:

```
public ActionResult GetUploadedPdfs(int id)
    {
        var model = _unitOfWork.AssignmentProtocols.GetById(id);
        DocumentRepository documentRepository = new DocumentRepository();
        foreach (FilePath filePath in model.DocumentPath)
        {
            byte[] fileContent = documentRepository.Get(filePath.Path);
            return new FileContentResult(fileContent, "application/pdf");
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Details", "Inspections", new { id = model.InspectionCaseId });
    }
```

My view is as follows:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Se uppladdade filer", "GetUploadedPdfs", "AssignmentProtocols", new { Id = Model.ElementAt(i * 2 + n).Assignment.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-default", name = "document", target = "_blank" })
```

What I am simply trying to do is opening multiple documents in a blank page each. How do I loop over this list in the controller? is there a good technique to do it from the view? Thanks for help!

Comment: The basic programming mistake you are doing is having return statement in the loop and expecting the entire loop to complete. This loop never gets completed even if it's  not MVC. Coming back to your issue, you can not return multiple action results but you can return multiple values wrapped in a model class to the view or return JSON result containing multiple values. Can you explain what exact feature you are trying to implement which requires you to write this code? That will help providing proper solution.

Comment: My basic problem is how do I return each FileContentResult to the view through this loop. I know my logic is bad in here. Is there a way good way to loop over this inside the view. Thanks and sorry the vague question.

Comment: Use a List<FileContentResult> and loop in your view

Comment: @Rascal88 You cannot do it the way you are trying. You need to create a zip package to hold the files and return that.